# MVC passing values through several views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I have a login view for a user to authenticate: after he inserts his username and password, the next view has a section with `welcome, username` message. I pass this information through a `ViewBag.welcomeMsg` and everything is smooth.

When I advance to another view, that section no longer contains the message as the `ViewBag.welcomeMsg` is defined in the first login controller and gets erased after that.

I don't want write in every controller `ViewBag.welcomeMsg = "...";`

My question: is there a way to pass a variable like `ViewBag` that persists and can be accessed from every view of the web application? Like a static field?

Comment: Why not store the logged in user information in a `Session` variable?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to show the welcome message on your view when user is authenticated then just modify your view like this :

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <text>Welcome, @User.Identity.Name</text>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can check with the TempData which will be available till start of the next view rendering. so that you can set it to the other viewbag from tempData.

Answer (score 0):

It very much depends on how you handle the authentication process. If you are using `FormsAuthentication` for example, then the user information will be stored in `User.Identity.Name`. You can access `User` property from various contexts like controller, view, etc.

On the other hand if you are handling the authentication by yourself, my suggestion to you would be to do any of the following (I am writing this from top of my mind, so if I miss a name of a property, forgive me):

1. Store username in a cookie, and in Global.asax handle `PostAuthenticated` event where you will read the username (if authenticated) from the cookie. After that create a GenericPrincipal object with GenericIdentiy and assign it to a Controller.User
2. Store the information in a session (the easiest of all) and pass it around. However, the problem with this is if you have a sessionless controller in which case you cannot rely on this approach.

I wrote an article a long time ago about working with roles and principals, but you can get a picture on how to handle your problem with this solution http://mvcdeveloper.wordpress.com/2013/06/08/passing-user-roles-to-httpcontext-user/

Comment: I have a question regarding self authentication approach you did. I have seen in my project, we are using Global Static Variable to save the employee id. I am aware that using static variables is a bad practice. But can you let me know what are the problems with that.

Comment: By the way, this code has been working fine. We got more than 50000 users. On application start up methods and some initializer methods, we read the employee_id from a cookie and assign it to this static variable.

Comment: @sam113, Problems with what? Using static variables? It is a bad practice because you are sharing the same data among different instances. It might as well happen that five users will all have the same ID in your static variable. You don't want this.